# How can I make an isAuthorized() method in Eloquent ORM?

Tags: php, mysql, eloquent, laravel-blade, laravel-6

Can anyone explain to me in detail this part line by line? How can I make an `isAuthorized(@param, @param)` method in Eloquent ORM?

```php
class User extends Authenticatable
{
    public function isAuthorized($object, $operation)
    {
        return Db::table('role_permissions')
            ->where('object', $object)
            ->where('operation', $operation)
            ->join('user_roles', 'user_roles.role_id', '=', 'role_permissions.role_id')
            ->where('user_roles.user_id', $this->id)
            ->exists();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know if I'm correct on my guesses about `$object` and `$operation` but here I go:

```php
<?php

class User extends Authenticatable
{
    public function isAuthorized($object, $operation)
    {
        // You are checking if the current user has access to $operation method
        // on $object. E.g. App\Http\Controllers\UserController@viewAny.

        // This will output a query LIKE this:
        // SELECT COUNT(`rp`.`id`)
        // FROM role_permissions rp
        // INNER JOIN user_roles ur ON ur.role_id = rp.role_id
        // WHERE `object` = 'App\\Http\\Controllers\\UserController'
        // AND `operation` = 'viewAny'
        // AND `ur`.`user_id` = 1;
        // And then it will check if the value > 0.
        return Db::table('role_permissions')
            ->where('object', $object)
            ->where('operation', $operation)
            ->join('user_roles', 'user_roles.role_id', '=', 'role_permissions.role_id')
            ->where('user_roles.user_id', $this->id)
            ->exists();
    }
}
```

If this is what it is doing, you should look into policies: https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/authorization#creating-policies

And then to use the policy:
https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/authorization#via-the-user-model